# Why does my Javascript code only calculate my age only on the first click of the submit button only?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a java-script code which calculates a person age.
A user will enter his/her identity number in an input field and clicks submit. then the java-script code will calculate their age.

i do not understand why the java-script code does not calculate a different age when i change the identity number.

eg identity number 1:  7810104455082, identity number 2:  8001013355088 and identity number 3:  9502242235086

my html code below:

```
<input id="IDNumber" type="text" name="idnumber" placeholder="ID number" />

<input onclick="return validateID();" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />

<p id="demo">demo</p> <p id="demo2">demo2</p>

<div id="screen" style="width:600px; height:400px; background-color:gray;"></div>
<button id="display">Display</button>
```

my javascript code below:

```
<script>


function validateID() {   

    var ex = /^(((\d{2}((0[13578]|1[02])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])|(0[13456789]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)|02(0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])))|([02468][048]|[13579][26])0229))(( |-)(\d{4})( |-)(\d{3})|(\d{7}))/;


  var idNumber = document.getElementById("IDNumber").value;
  if (ex.test(idNumber) == false) {
    // alert code goes here
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Please supply a valid ID number" ;
    alert('Please supply a valid ID number');
    return false;
  }

    //Pull out Year and Month and Day for IDNumber
    var tempDate = new Date(idNumber.substring(0, 2), idNumber.substring(2, 4) - 1, idNumber.substring(4, 6));

    var id_date = tempDate.getDate();
    var id_month = tempDate.getMonth();
    var id_year = tempDate.getFullYear();
    // set variable of fullDate to insert in math calculation
    var fullDate = id_year + "/" + (id_month + 1) + "/" + id_date;

    //math time calculation to give mil and convert to years
    var d1 = new Date(); //"now"
    var d2 = new Date(fullDate)  // some date
    var diff = Math.abs(d1-d2);  // difference in milliseconds

    var yeardiff = diff / 31536000000;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The Age is " + Math.round(yeardiff);


}
</script>
```

Comment: try to remove `return` from onclick

Comment: Wow thanks a lot mate... :-)

Comment: it works perfectly now. How do i mark my question as answered? Thanks alot again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `return` on your `onclick`

```
<input onclick="validateID();" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```